# popup window not open in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have implemented a script to prevent the link in my mobile app on my ipad.

It works fine but I have problem now with the popup I have with jquery mobile.

The problem is when I use this script, the popup window doesn´t open anymore.

What can I do to open the popup window?

The script:

```
 (function(document,navigator,standalone) {
   // prevents links from apps from oppening in mobile safari
   // this javascript must be the first script in your <head>
   if ((standalone in navigator) && navigator[standalone]) {
     var curnode, location=document.location, stop=/^(a|html)$/i;
     document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
       curnode=e.target;
       while (!(stop).test(curnode.nodeName)) {
         curnode=curnode.parentNode;
       }
       // Condidions to do this only on links to your own app
       // if you want all links, use if('href' in curnode) instead.
       if('href' in curnode && ( curnode.href.indexOf('http') ||
              ~curnode.href.indexOf(location.host) ) ) {
         e.preventDefault();
         location.href = curnode.href;
       }
     },false);
   }
 })(document,window.navigator,'standalone');
```

Comment: any have an ideia... i haven´t solved it yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it...

**what i have done:**

instad to use the script i have write above, i only use this code in the `<a href=""></a>`.

```
<a onclick="parent.location='root/example.html'" id="ex"></a>
```

this allows me when i see my app in the fullscreen mode.. to navigate between the pages without to open it in the browser, the page loaded in my app.

Comment: Did you find a way ro open programmatically? Mine also works on desktop but doesn't open on mobile.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you need to open it programmatically.

```
$('#popupID').popup('open');
```

Comment: omar i do it.. but dont open

Comment: @user2232273 maybe you're not binding it to the correct event.

Comment: i have tried a lot of things but the popup window still not open

Comment: Do you get any error? Try `.show();` at least to check if the popup div is in DOM.

Comment: where i have to write this?

Comment: Add a click listener to a link or a button, `$('#popupid').show);`. Can you post your html markup and how you tried to open it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31360/discussion-between-user2232273-and-omar)